# issue with bracket multiplication in latex conversion

Tags: python, latex

I have a expression like `-x(4)` which I'm parsing using `parse_latex` and I get the result as `-4*x` and if I try `-4(x)` which is same as `-x(4)` , I'm getting the result as `-x(4)`. Is there any difference between `-x(4)` and `-4*x` in python.

```
class CheckAnswer(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        ex_no = request.data.get('ex_no')
        answer = request.data.get('answer')
        try:
            get_question = MathExamTbl.objects.get(ex_no=ex_no)
        except MathExamTbl.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'question': 'invalid'})
        parsed_answer = parse_latex(r"{}".format(answer))
        correct_answer = parse_latex(r"{}".format(get_question.correct_ans))
        if str(answer) == str(get_question.question_body):
            return Response({"message": "answer not allowed", 'data': str(parsed_answer), 'status': 200, 'error_code': error_codes['not_allowed']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        if parsed_answer.simplify(rational=True) == correct_answer.simplify(rational=True):
            return Response({"message": "correct answer", 'data': str(parsed_answer), 'status': 200, 'error_code': error_codes['ok']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"message": "wrong answer", 'status': 400, 'error_code': error_codes['not_ok']}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```